# Can you create a compund index including _id or key?

Tags: indexing, arangodb

Suppose I have the following document:

```
{_id: "mycollection/key",
 _key: "key",
 users: ["userKeyA","userKeyB","userKeyC"]
}
```

Can I create a persistent Index for *_id* and *users* to speed up my lookup time for user keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
db.<collection>.ensureIndex({fields:["users", "_key"], type:"persistent");
```